# How to read data-bind property value from config file and bind i to view

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, bind, knockout-2.0, knockout-3.0

In knockout, I need to take the property and value to bind from a configuration file and bind it to view. How can I achieve that?

e.g.

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: {data: data, as : 'tbData'}">
  <!-- ko foreach: $parent.bindingProperties -->
    <input type="text" data-bind="value:tbData.spec"/>
  <!-- /ko -->
//some code
</tbody>
```

I need to read "value:tbData.spec" from js file. How can I write a suitable JS function and bind it to the view by calling it?

The configuration file is a js file. The config file is like

```
bindingProperties : [{'value': 'tbData.spec'}]
```

Comment: You have a `foreach` example in the documentation here http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html . You will need to replace `value:tbData.spec` with just `value: spec`

Comment: What kind of configuration file?

Comment: @JasonSpake Thanks for this question. I have edited the question for more clarity.

Comment: @GôTô I need to read value: spec from the configuration and place it in data-bind. How can I do that? I have edited the question for more clarification.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you're currently loading the configuration file, but if you can dump its contents into an observable, here's how you could go about binding it to the UI. I've made a quick binding that will manually apply other bindings by name-value pairs. It's not something I've used before so it's not well tested and it's certainly not robust just more of a proof of concept.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.applyBindings = {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, data, bindingContext) {
        var bindings = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor()) || {}; //should be an object with multiple properties like: { bindingName: propertyName }
        for (var name in bindings) {
            if (bindings.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
                var binding = {};
                var target = data[bindings[name]];
                binding[name] = function () { return target; };

                ko.applyBindingAccessorsToNode(element, binding, bindingContext);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and here's a jsFiddle of it in action: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jlspake/16z6gL17/)